# How to purge my deleted files

Tags: uninstall, delete, purge

I had un-installed a package and deleted all of its files/directories. But still when I locate the package, i can find the deleted files in list while in actual they are not present. I cant access those deleted directories nor can access its config files in /etc.

I gave my server a restart but didn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should always uninstall package with `apt-get purge packagename` if you what to completely remove them from your system.

Don't use locate to actually find deleted files, it does not work this way:

`locate` reads one or more databases prepared by `updatedb` and writes file names matching at least one of the PATTERNs to standard output, one per line.
By default, `locate` does not check whether files found in database still exist.

Run `sudo updatedb` and check again with your locate command, deleted files should not be listed.

Comment: I had removed the package with apt-get but still left with these files...tmp$ locate openerp
/etc/init.d/openerp
/etc/rc0.d/K21openerp
/etc/rc1.d/K21openerp
/etc/rc2.d/S21openerp
/etc/rc3.d/S21openerp
/etc/rc4.d/S21openerp
/etc/rc5.d/S21openerp
/etc/rc6.d/K21openerp
/var/cache/apt/archives/openerp_7.0-20140313-003151-1_all.deb
/var/lib/openerp
/var/lib/apt/lists/nightly.openerp.com_7.0_nightly_deb_._Packages
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openerp.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/openerp.postrm
/var/lib/openerp/filestore
/var/lib/update-rc.d/openerp
/var/log/openerp

Comment: Run `sudo updatedb` please to refresh the database used by `locate`